# Opening a fragment via button with navigation drawer active

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments, android-activity

So I'm having a slight issue using fragments, activities and navigation drawers.
Here's the scenario: -

I have a navigation drawer set up on my SecondActivity.java, this opens up fragments to my fragment pages. However, my main activity contains buttons which, when clicked, direct the user to the fragment pages.

My problem is, when user's use the navigation drawer to get to the fragment pages, it replaced the content_frame on the SecondActivity.java that contains the navigation drawer. However, as my main activity does not contain a navigation drawer, when it replaces the content_frame, it directs to the fragment pages without displaying the navigation drawer on them.

Unfortunately I am unable to copy in code as this is for college work.
I hope you understand.

My question is:- How can I direct the user to the fragment page WITH a navigation drawer, if the previous page does not have a navigation drawer?

Thanks in advance!

--edit--

To make it more clear...
When I use the navigation drawer on SecondActivity to get to ThirdFragment, the navigation drawer replaces the content frame on SecondActivity to ThirdFragment, without effecting the navigation drawer.
However...
When I click a button on FirstActivity (Which does not contain a navigation drawer) to get to ThirdFragment, the button replaces the content frame of First Activity to ThirdFragment.

Because FirstActivity does not have a navigation drawer, the ThirdFragment page is not opening with a navigation drawer as it would if I was to open the page via the navigation drawer on the Second Activity.

How can I open ThirdFragment via a button on a page with no navigation drawer, and have ThirdFragment open WITH a navigation drawer?

Comment: Add your code here to find the issue, and also question is not clear

Comment: As I stated above, unfortunately I cannot add the code due to it being for work - however, I have edited my question at the bottom to make it more clear, hope this helps?